# How do I connect database from MS sql server 2005 to application development tools (ADT)?

Tags: android, sql, database, adt

I need to connect my database from Microsoft SQL Server 2005 to an application-Application Development Tools (ADT). Can anyone help me with this and share some codes. I really need help on this on.

Comment: Ask about specific problem(s). Your question is not clear.

Comment: @Rajesh I do not know how to connect my 2005 sql server to ADT to call out the database. the codes I used are:

Comment: @Rajesh public void query(){
   Log.i("Android"," MySQL Connect Example.");
   Connection conn = null;
   try {
   String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
   Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
   //test = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.class;
   String connString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server_ip_address :1433/DBNAME;"
     + "encrypt=fasle;user=xxxxxxxxx;password=xxxxxxxx;instance=SQLEXPRESS;";
   String username = "xxxxxx";
   String password = "xxxxxxxxxx";
   conn = 
   }

Comment: DriverManager.getConnection(connString,username,password);
   Log.w("Connection","open");
   Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
   ResultSet reset = stmt.executeQuery("select * from DBNAME");
    
   //Print the data to the console
   while(reset.next()){
   Log.w("Data:",reset.getString(3));
//                 Log.w("Data",reset.getString(2));
   }
   conn.close();
    
   } catch (Exception e)
   {
   Log.w("Error connection","" + e.getMessage());
   }

Comment: How do i obtain the String Username and String password??

Comment: Please edit your question and add whatever you have tried. If there is an issue, someone might be able to help you. "Give me the codez" type questions are frowned upon in SO.

Comment: Am i supposed to hard-code my username and password into the main java file after creating the user in MS sql server 2005 in order to link my db and the java file? and how do i call out the db into my java file? @Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

your question is not enough clear, however if you are trying to connect/access Microsoft SQL Server 2005 database with android application then you should use http://jtds.sourceforge.net/ library to connect to it.

Hope this helps.

```
public class ConnectionProvider {
static final String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
static final String connString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://ip-address:port/database;user=saa;password=minds;";
static final String username = "saa";
static final    String password = "minds";
private Connection mConnection = null;



public static Connection getIPConnection(){

    try{

        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        mConnection=DriverManager.getConnection(connString,username,password);
        return mConnection;

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I downloaded the jdbc already. I do not know how to use that in order to connect my database from the 2005 sql server to ADT. Could you help?

Comment: you can do this depending upon your requirements, weather you want to connect to one db or more

Comment: but i thought we aren't suppose to code our username or password directly into the codes. and are the username and password be obtained from the sql server when I create the db user? @SureshBora